# Jquery Select element 2 positions further - another way to .next().next()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I am searching for a way how I could select a div element which is not the direct next one to the one which is "selected" by a click function.

```
<div id="click">(siblings)</div><div>text</div><div id="get this one"></div>
```

Now I would like to select the one with the id "get this one"  - in my code this id is not available. All the divs have the same class and do have siblings.
I could select the third one by `$(this).next().next()` but I think it's not the best way to do it.
Also there can be `div`s before the one which is clicked - so it's not necessarily the first one.

I tried the `:nth-child` selector but didn't find a solution.
Later I also may want to select the 13th one after the click one (or the 23th, 65th and so on). This means I would like to have a rather dynamic solution to this problem.

Thanks for your help,
Phil

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) with [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) for your dynamic approach, like this:

```
$(this).nextAll().eq(1) //0 based index, this would be .next().next()
```

This would allow you to get `n` siblings forward, which *seems* to be what you're after.

Comment: Ok, now i feel like an ideot. It's so easy - and it works, of course. It makes so much sense that i hate me for not getting it working by myself. But thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$(this).parent().find('div').eq(2).attr('id')` should work.

UPDATE( Added find('div')  )

Comment: This would always result in an empty element set, `.parent()` selects a single element, not siblings :)

Comment: Before, your answer had nextAll('eq:2').  Would this work the same way as what you have for your answer now?  What's the difference?

Comment: @d2burke - You're getting the 3rd element in the parent no matter what...this isn't relative to the *current* element, it just gets the 3rd one, no matter which you clicked.   Also my answer used `:eq(1)` for the 2nd, it's a 0-based index :)

Comment: @Nick - Ah, yes.  I see (regarding the relative selection).  I understand the index being based on 0, but I was more referring to the fact that you had the "eq:1" in quotes before...and I wondered if that were just another way to write it.  Thanks for pointing out the difference between your answer and mine.  Yours it more flexible for sure.

Comment: @d2burke - You can use [`:eq(2)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) as a selector as well, rather than a function call, but when I re-read the question and saw he wanted it dynamic..it's much easier to use `.eq(variable)` rather than `".eq(" + variable + ")"`, and it's faster to boot.